# Any ideas to cancel a function in the middle? Swift iOS

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, cancellation

I call a network task to fetch some JSON when user selects a cell in a `UICollectionView`. This is `asynchronous` so the UI remains active whilst the data is being retrieved. Allowing user to select another cell in the `UICollectionView`. I do not want to stop this but I do want a way to cancel the first function call and call the new method for the now selected cell.

Is there a way to in perhaps `didDeselectItemAt indexPath:` to cancel any currently executing tasks?

I was thinking to place a "please wait" modal view over the UI which would prevent a second cell selection until the function returned. Is this my best option or is there a better way?

Comment: If you are using NSOperationqueue, the you can cancel.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use a NSOperationQueue to create and keep track of the asyncronous requests and cancel them when necessary.

See the answers to this other question here:
[GCD cancel async block?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21795882/gcd-cancel-async-block)

Answer (score 2):

By maintaining separate threads using `NSOperationQueue` enables controls over tasks in the middle of execution whereas `GCD` wont allow the same but both works for background and foreground execution of particular task mechanism.

- `GCD` is a lightweight way to represent units of work that are going to be executed concurrently. You don’t schedule these units of work; the system takes care of scheduling for you.
- `NSOperation` adds a little extra overhead compared to GCD, but you can add dependency among various operations and re-use, cancel or suspend them.

Sample:

```
var backgroundQueue = NSOperationQueue()
    backgroundQueue.addOperationWithBlock(){
        println("hello from background")
        NSOperationQueue.mainQueue().addOperationWithBlock(){
            self.theLabel.text = "updated from main thread"
        }
    }
```

Now can do various operation provided `NSOperationQueue` over `backgroundQueue` variable.

Comment: +1 for explaining why GCD may not be the best solution here. Also see this answer for a brief comparison of NSOperation and GCD: stackoverflow.com/a/10375616/563802

Comment: `addOperationWithBlock()` creates an NSOperation whose task cannot be cancelled. That is, your proposed solution cannot solve the OPs problem.

Answer (score 1):

You can submit your networking tasks as `NSOperations` to an `NSOperationQueue`.

`NSOperation` has a cancel method, and `NSOperationQueue` has a `cancelAllOperations` method.